# Getting 403 forbidden

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to create the users in keycloak from java application. I am able to create users and also assign roles to the newly created users in the master realm. I have created my own realm and also added some roles in the newly created realm. While adding the users and assigning roles to the newly created users I am getting the below exception
`javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException: HTTP 403 Forbidden`

I am getting an exception in the below line
`RoleRepresentation testerRealmRole = realmResource.roles().get("rolename}").toRepresentation();`

I have created the {rolename} in the realm. I am not able to find what is missing. Please, anyone, help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: { is missing in  quotes

Comment: You did not share the full code what exactly you are doing. Did you test your code if it is working with master realm or not?

Answer (score -1):

Use the below line of code

```
 RoleRepresentation testerRealmRole =
 realmResource.roles().get("{rolename}").toRepresentation();
```

Comment: I have used the above code still the exception is there